# Batch File wouldn't allow me to log in

Tags: linux, batch-file, unix, ftp

```
@echo off
set datetoday=%DATE:~10,4%%DATE:~4,2%%DATE:~7,2%
set /a batchdate=%datetoday%-1
cd c:\batchreports\DAYENDREPORTS\PREDAYEND\%batchdate%

ftp 192.168.18.188
username
password
cd autoemail
send DEALS_ENTERED_TODAY_ALL_2OM_UP_20170813.xls
bye
exit
```

When I try to run the code line by line in cmd prompt it works properly but if I run the bat file itself, it just prompts the login screen, which means my code stops working at the line of username.. what should I do so that the code will proceed?

Comment: What does `%batchdate%` expand to when `%datetoday%` is `20170801`? I'll wager not `20170731`.

Comment: that line of code stores yesterday's date in a variable it works properly but its not the problem..

Comment: I tried the Link Provided by Martin, implementing these new changes, the transfer was successful however, the file format of the excel seems to have changed. I can't open it.

Comment: @BenedictSolpico, as I said, I'm wagering that it doesn't, my assessment is that `20170801-1=20170800` not `20170731`. _As a side note, I placed my information as a comment because it is an issue with your code but not an answer to your question._

Comment: You remembered to include `bin` as one of your FTP commands, right?

Comment: yes I did.. but the output is still corrupted

Comment: So accept that this question is duplicate and start a new question for your new problem.

Answer (score 0):

To securely get yesterdays date you can't simply subtract one from todays date if this will swap the month as Compo already pointed out.

```
@echo off
For /f %%Y in (
  'powershell -NoP -C "(get-date).AddDays(-1).ToString(\"yyyyMMdd\")"'
) Do Set Yesterday=%%Y
Set "Folder=c:\batchreports\DAYENDREPORTS\PREDAYEND\%yesterday%"
Pushd "%folder%"||(Echo Can't locate %folder% &Pause&Exit /B 1)

> ftpscript.ftp (
echo host 192.168.18.188
echo username
echo password
echo cd autoemail
echo send DEALS_ENTERED_TODAY_ALL_2OM_UP_%Yesterday%.xls
echo bye
)
(ftp -i -s:ftpscript.ftp 2>&1 >ftpscript.log) && (Del ftpscript.*) || (
Echo An error occured, view log:
more < ftpscript.log
pause
Exit /B 1
)
Exit /B 0
```

Comment: @Compo thanks for the edit, missed.